# Qual a diferença do ./ e do ../ no php?

Tags: php

Estive tentando colocar uma parte do meu código com `../diretório/arquivo.php`, não funcionava de jeito nenhum, dai acidentalmente coloquei apenas 1 ponto, funcionou, tem alguma diferença entre esses? 
Eu nem sabia da existência do outro, tentei pesquisar mas não consigo achar nada relacionado por incrível que pareça...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso, o problema não é  do PHP em si. Mas nas nomenclaturas dessas classes especiais para se designar um  caminho.

O ponto único (.) representa a própria pasta, ou seja, o caminho no qual já  está  trabalhando.

Pontoa duplos (..) são  usados para indicar um caminho superior, ou seja, se eu estiver no "C:\arquivosPessoais", se eu quiser "subir" uma casa na árvore  de diretórios, uso o pontos duplos.

**Uma curiosidade:** no Windows, quando criamos uma pasta com nome "." ou "..", ele retorna uma mensagem de erro inesperado, ao invés de detalhar a causa.

**EDIT:** (Obrigado a @ItWasntMe)

Para fins de consulta, você pode encontrar um conteúdo mais avançado no [site da Microsoft.](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, estou um pouco confuso, pois no caso utilizei o (.) como se fosse (..), e o mais estranho é que está funcionando, o meu objetivo era voltar uma pasta anterior, entrar em outra pasta e referenciar um arquivo nela e o (.) está funcionando normalmente para isso, como se fosse o (..), queria entender o motivo disso ter acontecido

Comment: Agradeço muito pessoal!